# How to set a default/preferred window size for a Mac Catalyst app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uikit, mac-catalyst

I have an iOS app that I have enabled Catalyst for. One function in the app opens a new window. By default, this window opens very large but I need a way to make it smaller by default. I know you can set `windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize` and `.maximumSize`, but that then limits the window to my preferred size. I'd like to make it so the window opens a certain size, say `500x800` by default, but can be expanded by the user to whatever they want.

I have tried `window?.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 800))` in the `SceneDelegate`, but it has no effect.

Visual example:
[image: Image showing my goal window size versus the default window size]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out, so I'll help anyone with this issue in the future. Set your `.maximumSize` as your preferred size. Then after setting the window, use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {` to set the `.maximumSize` again, but this time what you want to be the actual maximum window size.

My full code:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        let toolbarDelegate = NewSchoolworkToolbar()
        let toolbar = NSToolbar(identifier: "main")
        windowScene.title = "New Schoolwork"
        if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
            titlebar.toolbar = toolbar
            titlebar.toolbarStyle = .unified
            titlebar.separatorStyle = .shadow
        }
        #endif
        
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            let newClassworkView = NewClassworkTableViewController()
            
            
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 500)
            // This will be your "preferred size"
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 800)
            
            window.rootViewController = newClassworkView
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            // This will be your actual size.
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 9000, height: 9000)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will force the specified size on every app start, discarding the user preferred window size from a previous app run!

Answer (score 2):

Following Dylan's great tip,

```
func tidyCatalystWindow() {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
     .forEach { ws in
        ws.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 500, height:800)
        ws.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 800)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            ws.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 9000, height: 9000)
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```

It's that easy.

Comment: This will force the specified size on every app start, discarding the user preferred window size from a previous app run!

Comment: @TomášKafka that's definitely true but (1) Catalyst is a very imperfect system (as of writing) and (2) there are plenty of apps where you indeed do not wish to use the previous window size memory, when you launch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the window size and position from a previous run this might be the right solution for you:

First of all you have to implement a `SceneDelegate` for your app. That’s straightforward for UIKit but a little more complicated for SwiftUI. Take a look at this post for that:
https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/app-delegate-scene-delegate-swiftui/

It’s a good idea to remember the corresponding window scene in the delegate:

```
class MySceneDelegate: NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var scene: UIWindowScene?                           // remember our window scene
…
```

And then you implement this delegate function:

```
    …
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)                      // only for running on a Mac
        guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
        self.scene = windowScene                        // remember our window scene
        var preferredRect: CGRect? {                    // is a size preference present?
            var rect: CGRect?                           // by default its not
            let width = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: MyMessages.windowSizeWidth)
            let height = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: MyMessages.windowSizeHeight)
            let x = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: MyMessages.windowOriginX)
            let y = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: MyMessages.windowOriginY)
            if width > 0 && height > 0 {                // we do have a valid size
                rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
            }
            return rect                                 // return the rect (or nothing)
        }
        if let rect = preferredRect {                   // we do have a rect
            let geoPrefs = UIWindowScene.GeometryPreferences.Mac(systemFrame: rect)
            windowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(geoPrefs) // apply it to the current scene
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

To store the current geometry of your window you can use any `View` in your app with a `GeometryReader`:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sceneDelegate: MySceneDelegate
…
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
…
            .onChange(of: geo.size) {               // size changed
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)                  // are we running on a Mac?
                if let rect = sceneDelegate.scene?.effectiveGeometry.systemFrame {  // get the system frame from the scene delegate
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(rect.width, forKey: MyMessages.windowSizeWidth)       // and set the user defaults
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(rect.height, forKey: MyMessages.windowSizeHeight)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(rect.origin.x, forKey: MyMessages.windowOriginX)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(rect.origin.y, forKey: MyMessages.windowOriginY)
                }
#endif
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of this is necessary if the user has the "Close windows when quitting an application" setting disabled in the macOS Settings. If disabled, when the user restarts the app, all previous scenes in their previous size will automatically be created. No code is needed to remember the size.